# Snackbar coming below the software buttons in Marshmallow

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-snackbar

My Snackbar coming below the software buttons in Marshmallow:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried changing the view, but it is not helping.

Comment: I have inflated Snackbar in my fragment using parent layout of View.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually Snackbar requires the CoordinaterLayout or window decor's content which are considered as parent layout for Snackbar. Previously, it was not getting any parent layout so it directly considered WindowManager layout as parent layout. Using CoordinaterLayout as parent layout it, solved the problem.

The sample code for CoordinaterLayout is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:nimbuzz="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```